# Amount of Compositions of a Number n into k parts when the components are limited to the range [1;m] with m<n

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, binomial-coefficients

The number of compositions of a number n into k parts is given by the binomial coefficent ${n-1 \choose k-1}$.

Is there a closed formula to this question, when the summands of the composition are limited to a range [1;m] where m is an arbitrary number strictly smaller than n?

Example: Compositions of n=6 into k=3 parts with m = 3

(2,2,2),(1,2,3),(1,3,2),(2,1,3),(2,3,1),(3,1,2),(3,2,1)

gives us 7 different compositions. The unrestricted composition has size

${5 \choose 2} = 10$

I tried this out for multiple combinations of numbers and I could not figure out a rule or a pattern that held for every combination of n,k and m.

Comment: In other words, you're asking for the number of ways you can make a total of $n$ throwing $k$ dice, each with sides numbered from $1$ to $m$. This restatement doesn't help to solve the problem mathematically, but might be helpful in trying to look up the answer.

Comment: @bof this is exactly it. I tried searching for the problem from a perspective of throwing dice, but I could not find a concise answer.

Comment: The generating function would be $(x^1+x^2+\dots+x^m)^k$ and looking at the coefficient of $x^n$ in the expansion of this.  As for closed form expressions, you could make a rather ugly one using inclusion-exclusion... something along the lines of $\sum\limits_{i=0}^k(-1)^i\binom{k}{i}\binom{n-im-1}{k-1}$, where here $i$ represents the number of dice whose value is higher than what should have been possible.  This is at least made simpler than it could have been thanks to all the dice having the same number of sides.  If you mix dice, it becomes much uglier.